# SwipeView in Qt 5.10.0 Crashes when compiled with MSVC2017x64

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qml

I recently was asked to migrate my application from x32 to x64. Upon changing the compiler from MSVC 2015 x32 to MSVC 2017 x64, the application crashed as soon as it started. After some code commenting I've arrived at a minimal working example of the error code.

the main.cpp is like this:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

While my main.qml is like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    id: mainWindow

    SwipeView {

        id: swiperControl
        interactive: false
        anchors.fill: parent

        Item {
            Rectangle {
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "#ff0000"
            }
        }

    }

}
```

It seems to be the SwipeView what crashes the application. Any idea on how I can solve this issue without having to remove it? It is pretty integral to my application.

Commenting the Item makes the program work (it doesn't crash).

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone it is definitely a problem with the QML version used in Qt 5.10.0. I've upgraded to Qt 5.12.4 and now the problem is gone without changing any code.